# How to build UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: ios, multithreading, animation

- When using a `UIActivityIndicatorView`, it is possible to add this view to your view hierarchy and start animating it.
- After that you are completely save to block the `main thread` (not that this is a good approach), there is basically nothing that I know of, that could stop the `activity indicator` from spinning.

My question is:

1. How is this done? It seems like `UIActivityIndicatorView` uses its own thread for rendering.
2. Is this something that can be achieved with my own views?
3. I have a `CoreAnimation` animation that I want to keep playing while the main thread might be blocking for a couple of milliseconds.

How to do that? Thanks for any help or ideas!

//EDIT: To clarify my question: I want to know what Apple does to get `UIActivityIndicatorView` animating even when you block the main thread. When I trigger my own CoreAnimation and I block the main thread, the animation itself stops. Furthermore to the question what Apple does to achieve that under the hood, I want to know, if I can achieve this myself, with public API.

Comment: your question is unclear

Answer (score 0):

You best solution is to use a background thread for long processing while keeping the main thread only for display purpose. That way, you will be able to display your view without blocking and run your long precessing at the same time.

You can use [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW3) dispatch_async to run your long processing code on another thread and then call dispatch_async on the main thread to refresh your UI.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
               ^{
                   // Your long processing code

                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                 ^{
                                   // Refresh UI here
                                  });
               });
```

Comment: I know that I can do that. My question however is more about what Apple is doing this the activity indicator. Even though we do the heavy work in background threads, there are still tons of reasons that could lead to a little jiggle during the animation.